# Controller spec & strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, strong-parameters

Very basic controller spec failing because something with my strong parameters set up is wonky?

```
class OrdersController
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.valid?
      ...
  end

  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).and_permit(:email)
  end
end
```

Test code:

```
describe OrdersController, "Create action", type: :controller do
  it "should call valid? method" do
    Order.any_instance.should_receive(:valid?)
    post :create, order: {email: "test@example.com"}
  end
end
```

Outcome:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, order: {email: "test@example.com"}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `and_permit' for {"email"=>"test@example.com"}:ActionController::Parameters
```

Comment: shouldn't it just be `.permit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comment on the original post from jvnill hit the nail on the head, it is `permit` **not** `and_permit`

```
params.require(:order).permit(:email)
```

Comment: Meh, you aren't nearly too drunk until you contemplate creating an alias for `Parameters#permit` to `Parameters#and_permit` ... then you know you've had too many.